# Will bots crawl my page generated by javascript

Tags: seo, google-search, web-crawlers, search-engine-indexing, search-engines

I use simple javascript to generate pages based on thousands of products stored in a JSON object.
The page URLs will be like `/productList?keyword=XXX&page=x`. The `keyowrd` is what uses input through the search bar. Single product pages would be `/product?id=XXXX`. For both of the product list pages and product pages, the product info is retrieved from the JSON API using javascript.

My questions are:

1. There will be countless combinations of `keyword` and `page`, how would search engine bots crawl and index them?
2. If users search a product's name, what result would search engine give him? My concern is the products won't be searchable. But I read an [article](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/seo-javascript-good-bad-uncertainty/346708/#close) saying major search engines are able to execute javascript. So in my case, would search engine recognize my pages and products?

Comment: How does the json object work? Do you have a single json file that contains all the data for the thousands of pages that gets loaded in on each page load, or do you have thousands of separate json objects, one per page?

Comment: One JSON object

Comment: How large is it? I'm asking because page weight could also be a concern for crawling in that case.

Comment: Read more - https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/url-structure and - https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-strongly-recommends-using-html-to-get-content-indexed-quickly/269841/

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister The JSON string's length is less than 20k

Answer (score 3):

1. Search engines do not like to index [so-called "infinite spaces"](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2008/08/to-infinity-and-beyond-no). You should use `robots.txt` to block search engines from crawling your internal search results pages. You can block them by using a `robots.txt` directive like this:

   ```
   /productList?keyword=
   ```

   or this, if appropriate:

   ```
   /productList?
   ```

   Make sure you let Google index (don't block) your single product pages, at:

   ```
    /product?id=XXXX
   ```
2. You should test whether Googlebot can properly execute your JavaScript. To do this, use the [inspect URL feature of Google Search Console](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289?hl=en). You'll want to choose "Test Live URL" when you get the option to, then select [View tested page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289?hl=en#test_live_page). Scroll through the HTML view, which shows the final HTML that Googlebot was able to render from your JavaScript, and along with the screenshot you will be able to get an idea for what Googlebot is able to see. Bing may have a similar tool, I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am still not very clear about how I can make my products searchable in my case?

Comment: You'll want to make each product page accessible by exactly one canonical URL. Let Google index the product pages (finite), block it from indexing the internal search result pages (infinite).

Comment: Thanks. Having thought about this, I set single product's pages as  ` /product?id=XXXX`. Is this good?

Comment: @WenShenk That'll work!

Comment: Today I tested my product list page, product page and also normal page( not built with javascipt) using Search Console's test live url function. It seems Google bot won't load all of the js files and every time what JS files will be loaded is different: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/137607/google-bot-seems-to-often-fail-at-loading-jquery This surely is a big headache for me. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Search engines do not like "search result pages" in their search results.  They tend to push better pages out of the top 10 results, and create a bad user experience overall, since the user is NOT taken to the item they want, but must now scroll down through another search results page to find the item they want.

As such, it is best to exclude search result pages from search engines altogether.

The search result page should have

```
 <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
```

And the robots.txt should be set as Maximilian describes above, for all crawlers (*), not just googlebot.

The latter will prevent **crawling**.  The former will prevent the page from **appearing in search results**.  Not quite the same thing; a robots.txt blocked page with good link relevance will get a "shadow page" created for it in search results based on that linktext data. If MLB.com/yankees blocked crawling with robots.txt, they would still be #1 for "yankees".  So sometimes you have to let  the search engine crawl the page so it can see the "meta noindex".

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am still not very clear about how I can make my products searchable in my case?

Comment: @wen The search result page should have

 <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">

Comment: @ReinstateMonica I'm totally confused here. Isn't noindex,nofollow telling search engine to skip this page?

Comment: @WenShenk i am saying do that for your search result pages, not your product pages.  And actually "nofollow" is not needed.